# Python chart using matplotlib and pandas from csv does not show all x-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, charts

I have to chart a data from csv somewhere from my directory. I am using python by learning some samples online. Problem is, I can't find any solution to show all x-axis labels.

[image: x axis: Japan, maylay, sing, Thai, US]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

pathcsv = r'D:\iPython\csvfile\samplecsv2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pathcsv)
df.set_index('Names').plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: share sample of the data set

Comment: and what are you trying to graph?

Comment: And what is your graph actually showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by using `set_xticklabels` to set the names and `set_xticks` to show ticks for each country. Updated code is below...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

pathcsv = r'D:\iPython\csvfile\samplecsv2.csv'
ax =df.set_index('Names').plot()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df))) #Show ticks for each country
ax.set_xticklabels(df.Names)      #Show labels as in df.Names
plt.show()
```

**Output graph**

[image]